# C# code utilizing Async CTP and throwing InvalidOperationException "Task_Start_NullAction"

Tags: c#, .net, async-ctp

I call QueryJourneys that makes an asynchronous call to d2 but then it fails when attempting to download some content (XML) with the WebClient, also asynchronously.

I get the exception **InvalidOperationException** with the string *"Task_Start_NullAction"* as the only message.

What is wrong?

The calling code:

```cs
    autoCompleteBox.ItemsSource = await OpenAPI.QueryStation(e.Parameter);
```

The code behind throwing the exception:

```cs
    public static Task<IEnumerable<Journey>> QueryJourneys(
                                                 Point from, 
                                                 Point to, 
                                                 DateTime lastStart)
    {
        string str = cs_requestResultPage(from, to, lastStart);

        Task<IEnumerable<Journey>> t = d2(str);
        t.Start();
        return t;
    }

    private static async Task<IEnumerable<Journey>> d2(string str)
    {
        var webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

        string t = await webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri(str));
        var view = new ResultPageView(XDocument.Parse(t));

        return view.Journeys;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the call to `Task.Start()`. The task returned by an async method can't explicitly be started - it's already effectively in progress when the method returns. You can return it directly from the `QueryJourneys` method:

```
public static Task<IEnumerable<Journey>> QueryJourneys(Point from, Point to,
                                                       DateTime lastStart)
{
    string str = cs_requestResultPage(from, to, lastStart);
    return d2(str);
}
```

As an aside, I'd strongly recommend that you start giving methods more meaningful names, following .NET naming conventions.

(As another aside, it's always worth saying *which* method threw an exception - in this case it's presumably `Task.Start`.)

Comment: The exception was thrown here. I thought that I wrote that and I apparently did not.
      
`string t = await webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri(str));`

Comment: @RobertSundström: Really? That sounds unlikely - could you include the full stack trace? As I say, the bit I'd *expect* to fail is the call to `Task.Start()`.

Comment: Anyway. Thank you for you answer. 

I'm quite new to the syntax and sometimes it gets complicated. I was actually wondering about the launch of a `Task`. Did not think that `await` would launch it for me automatically. Wonder why I did that. Never mind.

Comment: @RobertSundström: It's not `await` that launches it - it's the call to `DownloadStringTaskAsync`. That returns you a task which is already "up and running".

Comment: Aha! I see the difference now. Well. Everything seems to work and I get the results. I will hopefully don't get into trouble in the future.